# Excel display Alerts despite Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I have a python script that every morning opens an excel file, refreshes it and saves as new file with todays date. Even though no changes occur between the `.SaveAs` and `.Close` and despite all precausions taken to not display save prompt, excel of course display a dialog prompting me to save or not before close. And to make this a bit more interesting, this doesn't happen every time, sometimes it can run for weeks without it happening, and then one day it just doesn't work.

Code sample:

```py
import os
import datetime
import win32com.client as win32
from pywinauto.application import Application

# set todays date
dt = datetime.date.today() 
# connect to Excel instance
xl = win32.dynamic.Dispatch("Excel.Application") 
# open the excel template
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open([path to excel file]) 
# set report name
report_name = "Pending Report - INTERNAL - " + str(dt) + ".xlsx"

# refresh data
wb.RefreshAll() 
# save as new file with todays date
wb.SaveAs(os.path.normpath(path + report_name)) 
# set excel not to display alerts - to not prompt for save before close
xl.DisplayAlerts = False 
# disable Events - to not prompt for save before close
xl.EnableEvents = False 
# set state of workbook to Saved to make sure excel sees the file as saved
xl.Workbooks(report_name).Saved = True 
# close file and save changes set to true, ie. save the changes upon close
xl.Workbooks(report_name).Close(SaveChanges=1) 

# looks for the save prompt - but the code never gets here, it halts on previous line waiting for input on dialog window
try:
    app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re=".*Workbook Before Close*")
    txt = app[u"Dialog"][u"Static"].window_text()
    if "Do you want to save the changes you made" in txt:
        app[u"Dialog"].YesButton.click()
except:
    log("l", "i", "Didn't find excel or dialog window, might not be an issue but the Save dialog check wasn't successful")
```

Anyone have any ideas, or know what I'm doing wrong here?
Just to be fully clear, I've tested different combinations of these xl.DisableEvents etc. also tried them separately, some seem to work for a while then one day suddenly it doesn't anymore. Since this is an automated scheduled task, when it halts, it just sits there until I get an angry email asking for the report.

Now I know a workaround would be to create another scheduled task that runs another py file, that checks for the dialog, but that's not the issue here, what I want to get working is excel to do as instructed - i.e. not displaying the save before close prompt.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
```

Comment: Care to elaborate why this would work? I don’t remember but I changed from that to dynamic dispatch because I occasionally got an error where I had to remove a folder “gen”-something in some arbitrary location and restart the python instance to recreate it correctly.